Continued fraction of Cahen's constant has partial quotients that are all squares
I am having trouble with an exercise about continued fractions. All I know about the subject is the sections preceding exercise 4.4 in the linked book
Exercise 4.4
Define $S_0 = 2$ and $S_{n+1} = S_n^2 - S_n + 1$ for $n \geq 0$; this is Sylvester's sequence.

Using Exercise 4.3 (seee below)show that the partial quotients in the continued fraction expansion of
$$
   C = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{S_n - 1}
   $$
are all squares.

Prove that
$$
   C' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{S_n}
   $$
has a continued fraction $[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n, \dots ]$ where for $n \geq 3$ each $\frac{a_n}{2}$ is a square.

Finally, show that $2C = C' + 1$.


(The number $C = 0.64341054628 \dots$ is sometimes called Cahen's constant.)
My try:
I haven't managed to do much, just substitute $S_n-1=S_n^2-S_{n+1}$ in the denominator
$$
   C = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{S_n - 1} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{S_n^2-S_{n+1}}=$$
But I don't know if this is useful. I have also proven by induction that
$S_n-1=S_0S_1....S_{n-1}$  Don't know how to link this to the exercise 4.3
Any help would be appreciated

Exercise 4.3
Prove that
$
\alpha = a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{q_n q_{n-1}}.$
Notes
Here $\alpha$ should represent an irrational number if I am not mistaken. Also the $q_n$ come from this: for irrational number $\alpha$
$$
\alpha = [a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n, \dots] 
$$
is the continued fraction representation
We define polynomials $p_n = p_n(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ and $q_n = q_n(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ as follows: $p_1(a_1) = a_1$, $q_1(a_1) = 1$ and
$$
p_n(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) = a_1 p_{n-1}(a_2, \dots, a_n) + q_{n-1}(a_2, \dots, a_n),
$$
$$
q_n(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) = p_{n-1}(a_2, \dots, a_n)
$$
for $n = 2, 3, \dots$.
Lemma 4.1. For $n = 1, 2, \dots$, we have
$$
\frac{p_n(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)}{q_n(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)} = a_1 + \cfrac{1}{a_2 + \cfrac{1}{a_3 + \dots + \cfrac{1}{a_n}}}.
$$
The polynomial
$$
C(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) = p_n(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)
$$
the continuant on variables $a_1, \dots, a_n$. (We also set $C() = 1$ for the empty set of variables.)
Also
$$
q_n(a_1, \dots, a_n) = C(a_2, \dots, a_n),
$$
Lemma 4.1 in the new notation
$$
\frac{C(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)}{C(a_2, \dots, a_n)} = a_1 + \cfrac{1}{a_2 + \cfrac{1}{a_3 + \dots + \cfrac{1}{a_n}}}.
$$
Reference book https://pdfupload.io/docs/735f9678
Edit: trying a suggestion in the comments:
$ C = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{S_n - 1} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{S_{n-1}^2-S_{n-1}}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(\frac{1}{S_{n-1}-1}-\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}) $ but it does not seem to be telescoping
Edit: Further hints:

There was a hint to solve  exercise 4.3 that is also used for exercise 4.4: that is:

From lemma 4.6 one can prove: $\frac{p_n}{q_n} = a_1 + \sum_{j=2}^n  \frac{(-1)^j}{q_j q_{j-1}}$

Notice that Sylvester's sequence converge very quickly

You must compare the denominators of the terms in the series to $q_j q_{j-1}$ to link it to exercise 4.3 and its hint. From there deduce the form of the $q_j$'s and the $a_i$'s


I made some calculations truncating the series to 1 , 2 or 3 terms and I get $[1,1,1...k^2]$ for the rational approximations everytime, so somehow this should translate to the infinite case.

Have you considered writing down the partial sums and seeing what telescoping does to them?

@WatsonLadd I tried your suggestion, see my edit. It would be telescoping if it were not by that $(-1)^n$ that can't be fixed Any idea?

I have also noted $S_{n+1}-S_n=(S_n-1)^2$

Sorry, I was thinking about exercise 4.3 but I misunderstood what part you were asking about

@WatsonLadd 4.3 is just there to be used in 4.4 somehow. I am asking about 4.4, I have no idea what to do in none of the 3 parts

I don't think so. In fact I'm also confused how it applies: I feel there is supposed to be some trick to get information out of the convergents into the quotients applied here, maybe by getting some clever expression for what the fractions look like.

Answer to question 4.4.1
Denote by $C_n$ the $n$-th partial sum $C_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{S_k-1}$. We start by computing the first few terms of this sequence :
$$
  C_0=1, C_1=\frac{1}{2}, C_2=\frac{2}{3}, C_3=\frac{9}{14}, C_4=\frac{83}{129}, C_5=\frac{16277}{25298}, 
  $$
We observe that the denominators follow the OEIS sequence A006279. It is indicated on the OEIS link  that this sequence
(call it $d_n$) satisfies the recurrence $d_{n+2}=d_n^2d_{n+1}+d_n$.
This motivates the following definition :
Definition 1. Let $(d_n)_{n\geq -1}$ be the sequence uniquely defined by $d_{-1}=d_0=1$ and $d_{n}=d_{n-2}^2d_{n-1}+d_{n-2}$ for $n\geq 2$.
Lemma 1. For $n\geq 0$ we have $S_n-1=d_{n-1}d_{n}$.
Proof of Lemma 1. By induction on $n$. For $n=-1,0$ the equality can be checked directly. Now, if $n\geq 1$ and the equality is true for all $k \lt n$, we have
$$
S_{n}-1=S_{n-1}^2-S_{n-1}=(d_{n-2}d_{n-1}+1)^2-(d_{n-2}d_{n-1}+1)=d_{n-2}^2d_{n-1}^2+d_{n-2}d_{n-1}=d_{n-1}(d_{n-2}^2d_{n-1}+d_{n-2})=d_{n-1}d_{n},
$$
as wished. This finishes the proof of lemma 1.
Similarly, if we compute and observe the first partial quotients for $C$, the sequence goes $0,1,1,1,4=2^2,9=3^2,169=14^2\ldots$. This motivates the following
definition :
Definition 2. Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be the sequence uniquely defined by $a_1=0,a_2=1$ and $a_{n}=d_{n-4}^2$ for $n\geq 3$.
Lemma 2. For $n\geq 1$, denote by $q_n$ the $n$-th continuant $q_n=C(a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_{n})$. Then $q_n=d_{n-2}$ for $n\geq 1$.
Proof of Lemma 2. The computation of $q_1=1=d_{-1}$ and $q_2=1=d_0$ is straightforward. Next, using continuant reduction (as in Lemma 4.4.(b) of the book), we have
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
q_n &=& C(a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_{n}) \\
 &=& a_{n} C(a_2,\ldots,a_{n-1}) + C(a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_{n-2})  \\ 
 &=& a_{n} q_{n-1} + q_{n-2}  \\ 
 &=& d_{n-4}^2 q_{n-1} + q_{n-2}  \\ 
\end{array}
$$
and the conclusion of lemma 2 now easily follows by induction on $n$ and definition 1.
Combining Lemma 2 with exercice 4.3 in the book, we deduce
$$
[a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots]=a_1+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{q_kq_{k-1}}=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{d_kd_{k-1}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{S_k-1}=C.
$$
this finishes the answer to question 4.4.1.
Answer to question 4.4.2
If we compute and observe the first partial quotients for $C'$, the sequence seems to go $0,3,2\times 1^2,2\times 3^2, 2\times 7^2,2\times 129^2,2\times 12649^2,\ldots$. If we denote by $(e_n)_{n\geq 1}$ the sequence $1,3,7,129,12649 \ldots$, inspired by the preceding recursion for $d_n$ (where $d_n$ divides $d_{n+2}$), we guess the relation $e_{n+2}=e_n(1+2e_ne_{n+1})$. This motivates the following
definition :
Definition 2. (a) Let $(e_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be the sequence uniquely defined by $e_1=1,e_2=3$ and $e_{n+2}=e_n(1+2e_ne_{n+1})$ for $n\geq 0$.
(b) Let $(a'_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be the sequence uniquely defined by $a'_1=0,a'_2=3$ and $a'_{n}=2e_{n-2}^2$ for $n\geq 3$.
Lemma 3. For $n\geq 1$, denote by $q'_n$ the $n$-th continuant $q'_n=C(a'_2,a'_3,\ldots,a'_{n})$. Then $q'_n=e_{n}$ for $n\geq 1$.
Proof of Lemma 3. The computation of $q'_1=1=e_1$ and $q'_2=3=e_2$ is straightforward. Next, using continuant reduction (as in Lemma 4.4.(b) of the book), we have
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
q'_n &=& C(a'_2,a'_3,\ldots,a'_{n}) \\
 &=& a'_{n} C(a'_2,\ldots,a'_{n-1}) + C(a'_2,a'_3,\ldots,a'_{n-2})  \\ 
 &=& a'_{n} q'_{n-1} + q'_{n-2}  \\ 
 &=& 2e_{n-2}^2 q'_{n-1} + q'_{n-2}  \\ 
\end{array}
$$
and the conclusion of lemma 3 now easily follows by induction on $n$ and definition 2.(a).
Combining Lemma 3 with exercice 4.3 in the book, we deduce
$$
[a'_1,a'_2,a'_3,\ldots]=a'_1+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{q'_kq'_{k-1}}=
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{e_ke_{k-1}}=
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{e_ke_{k+1}}
$$
We are not quite finished yet ; to show that the sum above is equal to $C'$, we need
Lemma 4. For $n\geq 1$ we have $S_{n}-1=2e_{n-1}e_{n}$.
Proof of Lemma 4. By induction on $n$. For $n=1,2$ the equality can be checked directly. Now, if $n\geq 3$ and the equality is true for all $k \lt n$, we have
$$
S_{n}-1=S_{n-1}^2-S_{n-1}=(2e_{n-1}e_{n-2}+1)^2-(2e_{n-1}e_{n-2}+1)=4e_{n-1}^2e_{n-2}^2+2e_{n-1}e_{n-2}=2e_{n-1}(2e_{n-1}e_{n-2}^2+e_{n-2})=2e_{n-1}e_{n},
$$
as wished. This finishes the proof of Lemma 4.
We are now going to use Lemma 4, but we must add a small modification to make a domino sum appear. Since
$$
\frac{1}{e_ke_{k+1}}=\frac{2}{S_{k+1}-1}=\frac{2}{S_{k}(S_k-1)},
$$
we deduce
$$
\frac{1}{e_ke_{k+1}}=\frac{1}{S_{k+1}-1}+\frac{1}{S_{k}(S_k-1)}=\frac{1}{S_{k+1}-1}+\frac{1}{S_k-1}-\frac{1}{S_{k}}
$$
and hence
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{e_ke_{k-1}} &=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{S_{k+1}-1}-\frac{(-1)^{k}}{S_k-1}\bigg)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{S_{k}} \\
 &=& -\frac{(-1)^{1}}{S_1-1} -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{S_{k}} \ \textrm{(domino sum)} \\ 
 &=& 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{S_{k}}  \\ 
 &=&  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{S_{k}} = C' \\ 
\end{array}
$$
this finishes the answer to question 4.4.2.
Answer to question 4.4.3
This is similar to and simpler than the preceding section : starting from $\frac{1}{e_ke_{k+1}}=\frac{2}{S_{k+1}-1}$, we deduce
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
C' &=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{e_ke_{k-1}}=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{S_{k+1}-1}=
2\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{S_{j}-1} \\ 
 &=& 2\bigg(-\frac{(-1)^{0}}{S_{0}-1}-\frac{(-1)^{1}}{S_{1}-1}+\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{S_{j}-1}\bigg)=2\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}+C\bigg)=2C-1. \\ 
\end{array}
$$

curiosity: why is it useful to find a sequence in the encyclopedia? Was it useful for this problem?

@darkside It's not really needed, I just thougt it interesting to mention. On the other hand, I got the recurrence relation from the OEIS, it would have been probably harder for me to find out the recurrence relation otherwise

So I think what's supposed to happen is that you magically divine from the similarity of the alternating series to $4.3$ the recurrence for the $a_i$ which can be found on Wikipedia. Once that's established the rest is straightforward.

I have further hints, it is still a bit unclear to me how to write an explicit solution, see edit
